# MvvmCross iPhone and iPad best practices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a question regarding `Xamarin.iOS` and `MvvmCross`. What are the best practices to show a `View` for iPhone and iPad with the same `ViewModel` but different `Views`?

If i put the same `ViewModel` to the two `Views` I get the following exception:

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exception.MvxException Problem seen creating
>   View-ViewModel lookup table - you have more than one View registered
>   for the same ViewModels

Is the best practice to create another `ViewModel` that derives from the first, and then from the `View` execute different logic dependently if the device is iPhone or iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create two `View`s for one `ViewModel`. `MvvmCross`, just like other MVVM libraries, uses reflection to create a `Dictionary` of `View` and `ViewModel` relationships. This is a one-to-one operation. If you try to register several `View`s for a single `ViewModel` in your container, a `MvxException` will be thrown as you pointed out yourself.

The simplest way to circumvent this behaviour, is to create a new `ViewModel` (and a new `View`) which simply derives from the first `ViewModel`.

```
public class ViewModelA
{
    public ViewModelA()
    { 
        // Constructor
    }

    // Properties, Methods, etc.

}
```

After creating `ViewModelA`, you can now create a new one, `ViewModelB` which derives from the former:

```
public class ViewModelB : ViewModelA
{
    public ViewModelA() : base() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MvxFormFactorSpecific attribute which is provided to you from MvvmCross  ,when You want to target iPad and iPhone for one viewModel do something Like below

```
    [MvxFormFactorSpecific(MvxTouchFormFactor.TallPhone)]
    public class ForTallController : MainController {


        public override void ViewDidLoad() {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
        }
........
........


    }
        [MvxFormFactorSpecific(MvxTouchFormFactor.Pad)]
    public class ForiPadController : MainController {

        public override void ViewDidLoad() {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

        }
........
........
    }

    [MvxFormFactorSpecific(MvxTouchFormFactor.Phone)]
        public partial class MainController : MvxViewController {


            public MainController()
                : base("MainController", null) {

            }

    ......
    ......
    }
```